# Oracle shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am running Oracle 11 on a windows 7 machine. I have this strange problem from this morning. When i try to connect to the database, it says 'shared memory realm does not exist'. However when i use Database Configuration Assistant, select a database and click next, it does 'retrieving database information'. During that time, when i connect to database it says 'Oracle shutdown in progress' message. Once the 'retrieving database information' is done (and i dont go beyond that step in Database Configuration Assistant') I am able to connect to the database without any issues.

I compared the environment variables and the windows services running before and after working and its all the same.

Question is, what does 'retrieving database information' in Database Configuration Assistant do that fixes 'Shared memory realm does not exist' problem?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

P.S. I checked other questions related to this subject in stackoverflow and didnt find anything useful or i did not understand it properly. So please do not close this question as duplicate.

Comment: "shared memory realm does not exist" usually means, quite plainly, that your database is not started.

Comment: Thanks Mat. If i am not wrong, oracle database runs as a service. And i saw that the database service was running before and after i did 'retrieving database information'

Comment: Just because the windows service is running, does not mean that the database is accessible.  You many need to perform a "startup mount" and/or "alter database open" command.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_27101_shared_memory_realm_does_not_exist.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Guys

I resolved the issue by doing the below.

- 1)    Choose Start > Programs > Oracle - HOME_NAME > Configuration and Migration Tools > Administration Assistant for Windows.
- 2)    Right-click the SID.
- 3)    Choose Startup/Shutdown Options.
- 4)    Choose the Oracle Instance tab.

Select Start up instance when service is started, Shut down instance when service is stopped, or both.

I restarted the machine and it worked.